# Is there any way to change || set template for dynamically created component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating component dynamically like this:

```
let factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BBGridDynamicComponent);
  this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
  const component = this.componentRef.instance;
  component.data= newData;
```

But i need a way to set this new component dynamical template.
Is there any way to do this? Would it be possible to create a dynamic component is this same manner that would have a dynamic template? For example a basic component that would display a template that would be defined at run time.

Comment: by `dynamic template`  what you exactly mean?

Comment: I mean passing template to component like property, so that same component could use different templates passed from constructor function/

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish overall?  To my knowledge there's no way to swap the template defined in the `@Component` but there's a few ways to use `@Directive`s and `switch cases` to choose between different elements based on whatever conditions you want them to switch by.  You can also use `*ngIf` inside the template to toggle different chunks of `HTML`.  With a little more detail on what you're doing I can give a relevant example. :)

Comment: ngIf is not an option. I need a way to use different types of template